# Passing '\' (backslash) character to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, escaping

I have a WinForm application within an Active Directory environment. One of these forms serves as user management, with the user names being stored on a table in a 2008R2 SQL Server DB

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DOMAINUSERNAME nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
    ID_ROLE int NOT NULL,
    USER nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
    CREATED datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UC_User UNIQUE (DOMAINUSERNAME)
    );
```

whose values are inserted through a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spENABLE (
    @DOMAINUSERNAME nvarchar(7),
    @ROLE int,
    @USER nvarchar(15))
AS
    INSERT INTO Users(
        DOMAINUSERNAME,
        ID_ROLE,
        USER,
        CREATED)
    VALUES (
        @DOMAINUSERNAME,
        @ROLE,
        @USER,
        GETDATE())
```

On the application domain, these are the relevant lines showing how the domain username string is created

```
string username = txtNewUser.Text.ToUpper();
string DomainUsername = String.Concat(@"MYDOMAIN\", username);
Roles Role = (Roles)cmbRoles.SelectedIndex;

DataBase.EnableUser(DomainUsername, Role, CurrentUser); //calls the sproc
```

And this is how the stored procedure is being called

```
public static void EnableUser(string _domainuser, Roles _role, string _currentuser)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spENABLE", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOMAINUSERNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _domainuser;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ROLE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)_role;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _currentuser;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now, this is the (to me) unexpected result:

```
ID  DOMAINUSERNAME  ROLE    USER            CREATED
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   MYDOMAIN\       0       MYDOMAIN\USER   2018-04-23 15:03:18.040
```

I'm sure the `_domainuser` argument is not empty, so the username part of the domain username must be dropped by the stored procedure. On the other hand, the current username - which is built in the same way! - is being correctly inserted. Maybe it has something to do with the constraint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set a breakpoint and have a look at the `DomainUsername` variable value or the `string _domainuser`.

Comment: Your method argument is `_currentuser` but you're using `_user` for the parameter.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @juharr yes, sorry... I have the (bad habit?) to write variable names in my language so I translated to English. My bad, sorry.

Comment: You can pass the domain name and username separately and combine both in stored procedure.

Comment: @a_programmer I think I'll do that, but what I find extremely odd is that _currentusername is in the EXACT SAME form of the _domainusername - checked right now throug debug. One is dropped, the other one is not.

Comment: @DavideVitali the size of the `@DOMAINUSERNAME nvarchar(7)` should be bigger I think. SQL server will trim the end if gets big size data than declared one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the type of the `@DOMAINUSERNAME` parameter from `nvarchar(7)` to `nvarchar(15)`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spENABLE (
    @DOMAINUSERNAME nvarchar(15),
    @ROLE int,
    @USER nvarchar(15))
AS
...
```

An `nvarchar(7)` can only store a string with a max length of 7 which explains why the `@DOMAINUSERNAME` value (but not the `@USER` value) gets truncated.

Comment: O-M-G. I can't believe I missed this. Thanks.